# How do you set a value to null with org.json.JSONObject in java?

Tags: java, json

How do you set a value to null with org.json.JSONObject in java? I can certainly read if a value is null by using isNull - but it seems like when I put null, it just ignores me:

```
JSONObject o = new JSONObject();
o.put("key",null);
o.isNull("key"); // returns true, buuuut...
o.has("key");    // returns false
o.isNull("somethingIHaventSetAtAll");    // also returns true, unfortunately
```

Comment: If you put null then it removes the key: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#put(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Try to set [`JSONObject.NULL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#NULL) instead of `null`:

> A sentinel value used to explicitly define a name with no value. Unlike null, names with this value:
>
> - show up in the names() array
> - show up in the keys() iterator
> - return true for has(String)
> - do not throw on get(String)
> - are included in the encoded JSON string.
>
> This value violates the general contract of equals(Object) by returning true when compared to null. Its toString() method returns "null".

Comment: could you provide example why it would violate the contract?

Comment: @voipp It violates the rule (from `Object.equals`): *"For any non-null reference value `x`, `x.equals(null)` should return false"*.

Comment: @rekire how to use this in `org.json.simple.*`

Answer (score 0):

For me with [net.sf.json.JSONObject](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jdk15/net/sf/json/JSONObject.html) I need to create a null `JSON` by

```
new JSONObject(true)
```

This is how I get class into groovy:

```
groovy.grape.Grape.grab(group: "org.kohsuke.stapler", module: "json-lib", version: "2.4-jenkins-2")
```

Answer (score 0):

I created this project https://github.com/leonardofel/JSON-java-put-null-fix

To change (or fix), just import the library to your pom.xml

this is how your code will behave:

```
JSONObject o = new JSONObject();
o.put("key", null);
o.isNull("key"); // returns true
o.has("key"); // returns true
o.isNull("somethingIHaventSetAtAll"); // returns true
o.get("key"); // returns null

o.remove("key");
o.isNull("key"); // returns true
o.has("key"); // returns false
o.isNull("somethingIHaventSetAtAll"); // returns true
o.get("key"); // throws JSONException "key" not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Utility Class or if you already have an existing one just create this utility method in it.

```
 class JsonObjectUtility{
           public static Object getJSONObjectValue(Object value)  {
              return value == null ? "null" : value;
           }
 }
```

then pass all input through this utility before passing it to the JSONObject put method as below: (i will use the code sample in the question)

```
JSONObject o = new JSONObject();
o.put("key", JsonObjectUtility.getJSONObjectValue(null) );
```

This shall print a json string as below

> { "key" : null }