# How do you set a value to null with org.json.JSONArray in java?

Tags: java, arrays, json

How do you set a value to null with org.json.JSONArray in java?

Comment: Take a look in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613754/how-do-you-set-a-value-to-null-with-org-json-jsonobject-in-java)

Comment: @eusoj I'm asking about JSONArray

Comment: Pls add code to illustrate the question.  You might add the tag JSON.