# Json array is not of proper format

Tags: android, json

Im trying to frame a json array of following form

```
[
  "1-35e03ac0b6ba442bb0d5fab3faef32fe",
  {
    "request": [
      "UpdateComplianceDetail",
      {
        "remarks": "Remarks",
        "next_due_date": "27-Mar-2016",
        "completion_date": "04-Apr-2016",
        "validity_date": null,
        "documents": null,
        "compliance_history_id": 23
      }
    ],
    "session_token": "1-35e03ac0b6ba442bb0d5fab3faef32fe"
  }
]
```

Following is my code that i use to create json of above structure,

```
private JSONArray getJsonArray(String encodedString) {
        JSONArray docArray = new JSONArray();

        JSONObject innerJson = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray innerJsonArray = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject inJobj = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray outerJsonArray = new JSONArray();
        SharedPreferences userDetails = getSharedPreferences("userdetails", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String session = userDetails.getString("session", "");

        try {
            innerJson.put("compliance_history_id", 23);

            docArray.put("null");

            innerJson.put("documents", docArray);
            innerJson.put("completion_date", "04-Apr-2016");
            innerJson.put("validity_date", mValidityDate.getText().toString());
            innerJson.put("next_due_date", mNextDueDate.getText().toString());
            innerJson.put("remarks", mRemarks.getText().toString());

            innerJsonArray.put("UpdateComplianceDetail");
            innerJsonArray.put(innerJson);

            inJobj.put("session_token", session);
            inJobj.put("request", innerJsonArray);

            outerJsonArray.put(session);
            outerJsonArray.put(inJobj);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return outerJsonArray;
    }
```

Following is the json that my code is creating,

```
 [
  "1-35e03ac0b6ba442bb0d5fab3faef32fe",
  {
    "request": [
      "UpdateComplianceDetail",
      {
        "remarks": "Remarks",
        "next_due_date": "27-Mar-2016",
        "completion_date": "04-Apr-2016",
        "validity_date": "null",
        "documents": [
          "null"
        ],
        "compliance_history_id": 23
      }
    ],
    "session_token": "1-35e03ac0b6ba442bb0d5fab3faef32fe"
  }
]
```

How can I be able to sort this out? I have put "null" within json array but its being recognised as a string and not as a null. also validity_date has to be null but it is a string "null"

Comment: This has been solved here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613754/how-do-you-set-a-value-to-null-with-org-json-jsonobject-in-java Hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docArray.length > 0 ? docArray : null` evaluates the length of `docArray`. If it's length is greater than 0 (aka, it contains items), it will put the array as the content of `documents`. Otherwise it will put `null`.

Same thing for `validity_date`. `isEmpty()` checks for `null` or `""` and if that's the case, `null` will be used in stead of the actual value of `mValidityDate.getText()`.

```
private JSONArray getJsonArray(String encodedString) {
    JSONArray docArray = new JSONArray();

    JSONObject innerJson = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray innerJsonArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject inJobj = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray outerJsonArray = new JSONArray();
    SharedPreferences userDetails = getSharedPreferences("userdetails", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String session = userDetails.getString("session", "");

    try {
        innerJson.put("compliance_history_id", 23);

        innerJson.put("documents", docArray.length > 0 ? docArray : JSONObject.NULL);
        innerJson.put("completion_date", "04-Apr-2016");

        String validityDate = mValidityDate.getText().toString();
        innerJson.put("validity_date", validityDate.isEmpty() ? JSONObject.NULL : validityDate.toString());
        innerJson.put("next_due_date", mNextDueDate.getText().toString());
        innerJson.put("remarks", mRemarks.getText().toString());

        innerJsonArray.put("UpdateComplianceDetail");
        innerJsonArray.put(innerJson);

        inJobj.put("session_token", session);
        inJobj.put("request", innerJsonArray);

        outerJsonArray.put(session);
        outerJsonArray.put(inJobj);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return outerJsonArray;
}
```

Comment: how about validity date?

Comment: it has to be set as null too

Comment: innerJson.put("validity_date", mValidityDate.getText().toString()); where the edit text is of null

Comment: @user1241241 does it ever happen that validaty_date is not `null`? Is there any condition or is it always `null`?

Comment: sometimes validity_date might have "null"

Comment: @user1241241 updated the code with validity_date included. Also included `JSONObject.NULL` by suggestion of @ferdy182

Comment: im checking it as follows, `            innerJson.put("validity_date", mValidityDate.getText().toString().equals("null") ? JSONObject.NULL : mValidityDate.getText().toString());
`

Comment: because it will contain a string "null" but my app crashed while doing so

Comment: @user1241241 Like I said, I updated my answer above with new code where validity_date will also contain null when it's empty. Use that code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `JSONObject.NULL`

reference: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#NULL
[How do you set a value to null with org.json.JSONObject in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613754/how-do-you-set-a-value-to-null-with-org-json-jsonobject-in-java)