# How do you set a value to null with com.google.gson.JsonObject in java?

Tags: java, gson, json

How do you set a value to null with `com.google.gson.JsonObject` in java? I can certainly read if a value is null by using isNull - but it seems like when I put null, it just ignores it:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
jsonobjToEra.addProperty("sun", Double.parseDouble(val));
jsonobjToEra.addProperty("mon", 22.333);
jsonobjToEra.addProperty("val", null); //ignoring it
```

Please note that I am using `com.google.gson.JsonObject` which is different from similar questions like [How do you set a value to null with org.json.JSONObject in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613754/how-do-you-set-a-value-to-null-with-org-json-jsonobject-in-java) in other posts in this SO.

**The JSON:**

```
[
  {
    "sun": 1122435343453,
    "mon": 1460538600000,
    "val": 45.900001525878906
  },
  {
    "sun": 1460538600000,
    "mon": 1460538660000,
    "val": 45.900001525878906
  }
  ]
```

Comment: Try using JSONObject.NULL instead of 'null'?

Comment: I'm not sure if my flag (duplicate) was false, removed the comment just in case (hopefully reverting the flag). Did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613754/how-do-you-set-a-value-to-null-with-org-json-jsonobject-in-java) already?

Comment: @MyGod I found a relevant link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-gson/SKLOi5zC1-4

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `com.google.gson.JsonNull.INSTANCE` like this:

```
JsonObject jsonObj = ...
jsonObj.add("val", JsonNull.INSTANCE);
```

Or if you want to complety remove value from serialization

```
jsonObj.remove("val");
```

**Demo:**

```
String json = "{\"a\": 1, \"b\": 1}";
JsonObject jsonObject = new Gson().fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);

System.out.println(jsonObject); // {"a":1,"b":1}

jsonObject.addProperty("a", 2);
jsonObject.add("b", JsonNull.INSTANCE);
System.out.println(jsonObject); // {"a":2,"b":null}

jsonObject.remove("a");
System.out.println(jsonObject); // {"b":null}
```

Comment: nice! I didn't know that.

Answer (score 15):

You need to use `serializeNulls()` of `GsonBuilder`. It enables Gson to serialize null fields.

**EDIT**

Usage of GsonBuilder

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
     .serializeNulls()
     .create();
```

Gson is made for converting Java objects to/from JSON. So you need to make a `Data Structure` or a `class` so that you can make an object of that and convert the whole object to json with `null`.

**See this example**

```
public class Country {

    String name;
    int population;
    private List<String> listOfStates;

    //getter and setter methods

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPopulation() {
        return population;
    }

    public void setPopulation(int population) {
        this.population = population;
    }

    public List<String> getListOfStates() {
        return listOfStates;
    }

    public void setListOfStates(List<String> listOfStates) {
        this.listOfStates = listOfStates;
    }

}
```

And when you use it:

```
Country countryObj=new Country();
  countryObj.setName("India");
  countryObj.setPopulation(1000000);
  List<String> listOfStates=new ArrayList<String>();
  listOfStates.add("Madhya Pradesh");
  listOfStates.add("Maharastra");
  listOfStates.add("Rajasthan");
  
  countryObj.setListOfStates(listOfStates);
  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
     .serializeNulls()
     .create();
  
  // convert java object to JSON format,
  // and returned as JSON formatted string
  String json = gson.toJson(countryObj);
```

Comment: Can you tell the usage of `GsonBuilder` to add the null values with example? I am not getting it to work.

Comment: No, I am only using JsonObject of gson. There is no way to have gson object to put in JsonObject.

Comment: @MyGod Gsons primary use to convert java objects to/from json. if you are not using that, you should not use GSON library itself. I edited my answer again.

Comment: This was the solution for me. With this setting, even inside of a custom serializer, a plain gson `context.serialize(null)` will return JsonNull.INSTANCE

Comment: the notice `serializeNulls()` is important and should be added to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by "rusted brain" if you use `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();` you will see those `null` fields when you convert the object to JSON.